# How to pass an image data by implementing parcelable interface from one activity to another?

Tags: android, parcelable

i have a main activity and second activity. on click of image button in main activity, it directs to second activity and shows a 6 avatar image buttons. i should select one of them and display back onto main activity. Can someone help me do this by implementing parcelable interface to pass data between activities?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing a model back to your main activity you can convert your model automatically to implement the Parcelable interface via this [tool](http://www.parcelabler.com/).

If you're trying to pass back a large object in your intent you might get  `TransactionTooLargeException` thrown. It really just depends on the data you're passing.